# How to insert into couchDB in laravel

Tags: laravel, couchdb

How to insert the records to couchDB in laravel. i have done the **retrieval** part but now I want to do **insert, update** and **delete** .

My retrieval code is below.

```
class couchdbcontroller extends Controller
{

    public function getdata()
    {           
        $content =null;

        try { 
            $client = new Client();             

            $apiRequest = $client->request('GET','http://localhost:5984/user/_design/userdesign/_view/user-view?limit=20&reduce=false');    

            $code = $apiRequest->getBody()->getContents();

        } catch (RequestException $re) {
            //For handling exception
            return $re->error;
        }

        return $code;
        //return response()->json($code);
    }
}
```

Inserting code below:

```
public function guzzle_insert_doc()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('PUT', 'http://localhost:5984/login/new_doc',[
            'uname' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'admin123',
        ]);
    //return $res;
}
```

**Error:** Client error: `PUT http://localhost:5984/login/new_doc` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}

Comment: What's your problem? Have you done any research, what have you attemp ? CouchDB is using raw HTTP to query the database so base on your Client() class, you just have to do a PUT request and pass the database in the HTTP body. If you want to use an existing library or simply look at it as a reference, take a look at [PHP-on-Couch](https://github.com/PHP-on-Couch/PHP-on-Couch)

Comment: I am now retrieving the data from couchdb using laravel. Now I want to insert the data into couchdb using laravel. Can you tell how can I do that... Pleasae refer my above code which I have done for retrieval part.

Comment: the example link which you gave is a php-on-couch. I am not using that plugin. we can use without plugin also. I have done the retrieval part but not i am not getting what shud I write to insert the data into couchdb like I wrote for retrieval

Comment: If you are on windows, try escaping your quotes in your JSON

Answer (score 0):

From my google search, you could do something like this :

```
<?php

$client = new Client();
$doc = ['title'=>'This is a new doc'];
$res = $client->request('PUT', 'http://localhost:5984/db/new_doc',['json' => $doc]);
```

I assume you're using Guzzle (If I am wrong, tell us what your are using)

I didn't test my code since I don't have time to setup a laravel project with Guzzle. See [documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html) for further help.

Comment: The above code which u gave its a creating a db.. Not inserting records to the db. if i mention already existed db name then it says database already exist. I want to insert the records into existed database..

Comment: I specified the _id twice which was a mistake but in the end, it's creating a document. See, I'm pointing the new document `new_doc` inside the database named *db* . I also passe the document data as a JSON object.

Comment: But now I get the error as "Client error: `PUT http://localhost:5984/login/new_doc` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}"

Comment: I have added my insert code. please look into that.

Comment: Would you not json_encode your data before storing it?